# How to delete the capture of window key?

Tags: virtualbox

Because I use virtualbox to run windows xp.

Normally when I press window key+e it can show file browser on xp,
but now my virtualbox's xp couldn't capture window key.

How to fix it?

Thank you~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following:
Install "compizconfig-settings-manager".
Run it.
In "Ubuntu Unity Plugin" set "Key to Show the Launcher" to something else than "Super".

Comment: How to run compizconfig-settings-manager and Ubuntu Unity Plugin? It shows compizconfig-settings-manager: command not found.

Comment: "compizconfig-settings-manager" is the name of package to install.
Binary to run is "ccsm".